# vb.net 2008 Facebook Chat-like ListView

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to create a user control that basically looks and feels like fb chat contacts list complete with friends lists and online/offline toggle buttons. How should I proceed??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd search codeproject.com for "Chat example" or "Chat application" and go from there.

You've got two elements.

1) the chat app (and underlying functionality)
2) the UI (ie making it "Look" like fb).

For underlying chat functionality, there's lots of example code out there.

Making it look like FB? That's just a question of skinning.